# access devise current_user extra fields in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm a rails and devise newbie. Now I added some custom fields to the devise model `User` like `username`. Now in the index, I want to display a link to access the `current_user`'s profile. So I have this code in my `index.html.erb`:

```
<div>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class:"nav-link" %>
    <%= link_to "Profile", user_profile_path(:username => current_user.username), class:"nav-link" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, class:"nav-link" %>
    <%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path, class:"nav-link" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But there is an error: `No route matches {:action=>"profile", :controller=>"users", :username=>nil} missing required keys: [:username]`. But if I change the username to email, everything is ok.

I have modified the `ApplicationController` as other posts say:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username, :address])
  end
end
```

But it does not help. So does anyone has any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Well it certainly looks like `current_user.username` is `nil`. Are you sure that `username` has been set? Open up the rails console and query for your user and make sure it has a `username`. `puts User.find(123).attributes.inspect`

Comment: ok you're right. I forgot to set the username field in my database. So dumb am I!

Comment: No worries, we all make mistakes. Glad you got it figured out.